# android: placing textView in an exact location of an image

Tags: android, layout

I'm building a menu for restaurant. I have this template menu image:
http://img.majidonline.com/pic/313384/background3.png
this is what I have to make:
http://img.majidonline.com/pic/313385/background3.png
here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background3">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

when I add any elements to this xml, the elements sticks to the top-left corner and I can't change its location to where I want.
I use values.xml for the prices so I can't put just a static image.
I'm using android studio and I'm new to android, so please help !
thanks

Comment: you have to define two different layers with same height and width as image.. then put your text widget to that layer..

Comment: I added a Linear Layout, and the layout itself sticks to the top corner. I don't know how to do that

Comment: set height and weight property..

Comment: post your code here..

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/background3"
    ></ImageView>
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:text="Dishes" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text=".............." />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        >
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12$" />

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="............" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="food" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Try this layout.. I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for helping. there are some problems:
first: the layout doesn't fill the whole body (fills almost 75%)
second: when the screen rotates (landscape mode) textViews are not in the correct place. that's why I didn't use margin. is there any other way?

Comment: take a look at these screen shots:
http://img.majidonline.com/pic/313388/b1.PNG and
http://img.majidonline.com/pic/313389/b2.PNG